# Ruby Models and Database Tables

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been going through Ruby on Rails and I found that you can create models and then insert create instances of those models, getting a Table of objects. So, how does SQL tables fit into that? Do we need them or are Models replacing them?

Comment: The [Active Record Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) Rails Guide answers all of these questions and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables are the persistence layer for your models.  Models are conceptual objects whose attributes can be manipulated in programs.  They are programming code wrappers around the persistence store where the underlying tables exist and the attributes are kept as column data stored in rows in those tables.  In memory a row becomes model instance.

The tables themselves are typically stores in a file system on some sort of durable and nonvolatile storage. These physical objects are managed by the DBMS.  The model object negotiates the data movement between your program and the DBMS. The term Object Relational Mapping (ORM) was coined to describe this.

So your question displays a certain lack of experience with these things. I suggest that you take a look at some general books on the subject of ORM and Object Oriented Programming. A search at Amazon will provide you with some likely candidates.  My reading list is a bit dated to provide you with anything more specific.